# How to do a FOR I in.. Loop in Pentaho ETL

Tags: loops, variables, pentaho

I am trying to loop through term years. the start_term is a static term 2010. Basically I just want to know how to flip the oracle way of doing a FOR Loop in Pentaho?

Below is what it originally looks like, but 'm not sure how to create it in Pentaho.

FOR I in start_term..End_term
LOOP
term_parm := to_char(I);

Thank you

Comment: 1) If you want to run a process for more then on value of parameter then you can use execute every row functionality of job level.
2) you can also use modified java-script step and write the java-script logic.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm new to using variables in Pentaho. I have multiple tables with the same name except for an id added on them and I need the data from each table so I wanted do a loop to where the from those table statement has the name but the variable will be the ids Pentaho loop through to get the data from each table.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through concepts first, it will make things easy.